# Creating a list of headings, sub-headings and sub-subheadings in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking to make a list of heading type 1, sub-heading type 2 and sub-sub-heading type 3, and each subsequent instance of a heading increments in excel. e.g.

```
Outcome 1
Output 1.1
Activity 1.1.1
Activity 1.1.2
Output 1.2
Activity 1.2.1
Activity 1.2.2
Activity 1.2.3
Outcome 2
Output 2.1
Activity 2.1.1
etc
```

Here is my formula - getting to be a complicated nested IF statement:

```
IF([@Column1]="","",
IF([@Column1]="Outcome", "Outcome " & COUNTIF(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Column1]]:[@Column1], [@Column1]), 
IF([@Column1]="Output","Output "& COUNTIF(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Column1]]:[@Column1],"Outcome") ***&"."&*** COUNTIF(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Column1]]:[@Column1],[@Column1]), 
"Activity " & "serious help")))
```

In Column 1, choose from a list of 'Outcome', 'Output', or 'Activity'.

In column 2, calculate the appropriate number, e.g. Output 1.2

If the row is empty, then nothing. - Fine

```
If it is "Outcome", count from the header until current row for the number of instances of "Outcome". - Fine    
Else if it is "Output", count the number of "Outcome"s there are. - Fine    
This is where it falls apart. Trying to calculate the number after the "." (bold and italic)
```

I need to count the # of instances of "Output", but then this has to reset to 1 each time there is a new 'Outcome'.

The logic I'm trying to follow is:

```
(# of "Outputs" from the table header until the current row) minus 
(# of "Outputs" from the table header until the last instance of "Outcome")
```

I've tried several attempts at calculating row number, but everything has been problematic.

The logic is the same for activities, though will complicate the formula even more and I haven't bothered to start on that until I can get level 2 sorted.

Does anyone know of a similar problem/solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using hidden helper columns, the formulas become much more manageable.  Use Column A to hold your "Outcome", "Output", and "Activity" data.

Then use column B to deal with `Outcome` numbers, column C to deal with `Output` numbers, and column D to deal with `Activity` numbers.  Merge the final results together in Column E.

In `B1`, `C1`, and `D1`, manually write in the first values (`1`, `0`, and `0`).

Then, fill down starting from `B2` with the following:

```
=IF(A2="Outcome",B1+1,B1)
```

This works by incrementing only if you have found your next Outcome.

Fill down from `C2` with the following:

```
=IF(A2="Outcome",0,IF(A2="Output",C1+1,C1))
```

This works by incrementing only if you have found your next Output.  It resets to 0 if you have a new Outcome.

Then fill down from `D2` with

```
=IF(OR(A3="Outcome",A3="Output"),0,IF(A3="Activity",D2+1,D2))
```

It's very similar to the prior formula, but resets on an Outcome or an Output.

Finally, in `D4`, merge it all together with

```
=B1&IF(C1>0,"."&C1&IF(D1>0,"."&D1,""),"")
```

`&` is a string concatenate operation.  By checking if the inner values are 0, we only concatenate `.` and the next number if the next number is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks Choirbean.  I've just found a solution, and had forgotten that I posted this quesiton.  My solution, in one big ugly formula is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863296/dynamic-multi-level-numbered-list-using-excel-formula

Comment: I also tried your suggestion, and it also works well, with a slight modification to also include the 'Outcome', 'Output', or 'Activity'. Note that I need to use it in a table, and therefore the table headings must be different, and must be numbers, using 0, -1 and -2 works for this, as it resets after the first Outcome is selected.
>=IF([@[Choose Level]]="","",[@[Choose Level]]&" "&[@0]&IF([@[-1]]>0,"."&[@[-1]]&IF([@[-2]]>0,"."&[@[-2]],""),""))

Comment: Oh, wow - the single-level formula is, indeed, big and ugly!  I tend to use helper columns to keep things simple because of a single awful experience having to debug a formula that I thought was correct, and was 4 screens wide.  It was so needlessly painful!  Since then, I've become rather religious about helper columns.  When I need my columns to be next to each other, I push the helper columns off to the side.

Comment: I've now hit a business logic bug. If there is level 1, i.e. Heading or Outcome, then it MUST go down to at least 1 Output (level 2) and 1 associated Activity (level 3).
- Outcome MUST be first.

- Output MUST follow Outcome.

- At least 1 Activity MUST follow Output.

- There can be as many Activity as required.

- There can be as many Outcome as required, but MUST be followed by Output.

- There can be as many Output as required, but as above, there MUST be at least 1 Activity under it.

Comment: Since that is the data being input in the first place, it doesn't sound like something a formula is great for.  What kind of output would you expect if the user doesn't follow that spec?

Comment: One that is not sequential and therefore illogical from a business sense.  But, since the user base for this is small -2 to 3 users-max 5, it's easy to manage and train them. I'll control it through the use of another column and 'error handling', that returns a message if they don't follow the logic. In all honesty, they know it and how it's meant to work, and I'm developing this for them so they don't have to type it out every time.  So I don't need the most sophisticated solution, just a workaround that saves them time. BTW, its for an NGO in Ethiopia. Tnx for your insight, spec helper cols

Comment: Since it's such a nice cause, I made some more helper columns for you to save everyone time.  In column A, you can let them put `.` separated numbers, so `1.4` would mean to make 1 outcome, 1 output, and 4 activities, while `0.3` would mean to make 1 output and 3 activities.  Then in column B (starting in `B2`) use `=IF(A2>1,"A",IF(B1="A",VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)),IF(A2>0,VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)),IF(B1>0,0-B1,IF(B1<0,B1+1,IF(AND(B1=0,A2=0),0,"Error"))))))`, and in column C use `=IF(B2="A","Outcome",IF(B2>0,"Output",IF(B2<0,"Activity","")))`

Comment: I did't follow that and both equations have problems.
What I have done is put data validation on the first three rows, which allows the choice of only Outcome, Output  and Activity respectively. Then I put in an 'error handling' column. Then wrapped column D with an IF statement that checks if an error was detected, and if so, then the numbering stops

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I wanted to create the multi-level heading numbers based on the indentation of list of texts. So the numbers must be generated automatically with a user-defined formula (UDF) like below:

[image: Computing next multilevel number based on indentation]

For this to work, you must type ="1" in cell A2. The same formula in A3 (below) must be copied down to A4:A14.

> =NextLevelNum(A2;IndentLevel(B3))

Function IndentLevel I took from https://professor-excel.com/how-to-return-the-indentation-of-a-cell-in-excel/

Function NextLevelNum I did myself. All code below.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IndentLevel(Ref As Range) As Long
  Application.Volatile
  IndentLevel = Ref.IndentLevel
End Function

Public Function NextLevelNum(prevNumRef As Range, level As Integer) As String
  Dim prevNum As String
  Dim nums() As String
  Dim prevLevel As Integer

  prevNum = prevNumRef.Value
  nums = Split(prevNum, ".")
  prevLevel = UBound(nums) + 1

  ' Ensure  1 <= level <= prevLevel +1
  level = WorksheetFunction.Max(level, 1)
  level = WorksheetFunction.Min(level, prevLevel + 1)

  ReDim Preserve nums(0 To level - 1)

  If level = prevLevel + 1 Then
    nums(level - 1) = "1"
  Else
    nums(level - 1) = CStr(CInt(nums(level - 1)) + 1)
  End If

  NextLevelNum = Join(nums, ".")
End Function
```