# Dynamic, multi-level, numbered list using Excel formula

Tags: excel, dynamic, multi-level, numbered-list

Folks,

I've managed to create a dynamic, multi-level, numbered list only using excel formula. This working correctly and I thought I'd share the result.  My only question is if someone wants to take this and try to simplify it. I can't seem to upload an example sheet (first time posting).

*Edit* I'm using a table called tbOOA, with 2 columns, Choose Level and Result. To use the formula, copy each line of the coded section below that does not start with > and copy it into one single (long) forumula.

The desired result:
Outcome 1

Output 1.1

Activity 1.1.1

Activity 1.1.2

Output 1.2

Activity 1.2.1

Outcome 2

Output 2.1

Activity 2.1.1 etc etc

```
>The formula explained:
>First choose if it is an Outcome, Output or Activity. If blank, then nothing
=IF([@[Choose Level]]="","",

>If it is an Outcome, put the word "Outcome" into column C
IF([@[Choose Level]]="Outcome", "Outcome " &

>and concatenate it with a count of the number of "Outcome" already chosen, limited from the header of the table, until this row
COUNTIF(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]], [@[Choose Level]]),

>Else, if "Output" is chosen, put the word "Output"
IF([@[Choose Level]]="Output", "Output "&

>and concatenate it with the number of "Outcome" from the table header to this line
COUNTIF(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]],"Outcome")

>and concatentate it with a dot and then
&"."&

>(This was the difficult part of the formula)
>count how many instances of "Output" there are between the last (most recent) instance of "Outcome" and the current row
COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]])*(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]]="Outcome"))),COLUMN([@[Choose Level]]))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW([@[Choose Level]]),COLUMN(([@[Choose Level]]))),TRUE),"Output"),

>Else, it must be an "Activity", so put "Activity" 
"Activity " &

>and concatenate with the number of "Outcome" from table header to this row, and dot
COUNTIF(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]],"Outcome")&"."&

>and count how many instances of "Output" between the last "Outcome" and this line
COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]])*(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]]="Outcome"))),COLUMN([@[Choose Level]]))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW([@[Choose Level]]),COLUMN(([@[Choose Level]]))),TRUE),"Output")&"."&

>and finally, count how many instances of "Activity" since the last "Output"
ROW([@[Choose Level]])-SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]])*(tbOOA[[#Headers],[Choose Level]]:[@[Choose Level]]="Output"))))))
```

Comment: What are the possible entries in the ChooseLevel column?

Comment: 'Outcome', 'Output' and 'Activity'

Comment: Unless I put "Outcome" in the first cell in the table I get errors everywhere. I can put the other two values in cells below that first value, but not in the very first. Can you clarify?

Comment: Agree. It is a slight bug. But logically, and from a business sense an Outcome will ALWAYS be first. I could put an extra error handling IF statement in there.

Comment: What restrictions are there on the order of entries in the ChooseLevel column? For example, if the first three cells are "Outcome", "Activity", "Activity" I get "Outcome1", "Activity1.0.3", "Activity1.0.4". Is that correct?

Comment: Again, agree that you would get that result. From a business sense, it will always be Outcome first, then Output, then at least one Activity.  From there, could be almost any combination.  However, if there is another Outcome, then it will always be followed by an Output.  There will always be at least 1 Activity below an Output.

Comment: Hadn't got to the stage of testing the business logic. So thanks for picking this up.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Professional Plus 2016. Would probably take some horrible nested IF statements to put in this protection in the formula.  My knowledge of Excel is not great enough to think of other ways to do it.

Comment: I asked the question about 5 months ago, and received an answer using hidden columns, that comes up with the same result, without one big ugly formula.  However, this solution also runs into the same logic issues as the above if the Outcome and Output are not selected in the correct order.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41061766/creating-a-list-of-headings-sub-headings-and-sub-subheadings-in-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1  Do you have any thoughts or suggestion?

Comment: Do you have the CONCAT and TEXTJOIN functions? Microsoft site says that they are available for Excel 2016, but "only if you have an Office 365 subscription".

Comment: No. CONCATENATE and TEXT but not CONCAT and TEXTJOIN, and no subscription.
I've put data validation on the first row to only allow Outcome and on the second to only allow Output. A bad work around that only works for those 2 rows.

Comment: Doesn't the third entry have to be "Activity" also based on what you've said?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: Nested IFs to check for errors in the business logic.  I'll put this in another column (and come up with a better message), and also put in conditional formatting to highlight 'mistakes'. This will be workable unless you have a brilliant idea.  Note I did this on a new sheet and named the columns slightly different.
=IFERROR(IF([@[Choose Type]]="Outcome",IF(OR(A3="Outcome",A2="Outcome"),"Outcome Error",""),IF([@[Choose Type]]="Output",IF(A3="Output","Output Error",""),IF(OR(A3="Output",A3="Activity"),"","Activity Error"))),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get it down to about half the size of yours.

**Array formula**:**

`=CHOOSE(MIN(ROWS(INDEX([ChooseLevel],1):[@ChooseLevel]),4),"Outcome1","Output1.1","Activity1.1.1",[@ChooseLevel]&COUNTIF(INDEX([ChooseLevel],1):[@ChooseLevel],"Outcome")&IF([@ChooseLevel]="Outcome","",SUBSTITUTE("."&COUNTIF([@ChooseLevel]:INDEX([ChooseLevel],MATCH(1,0/(INDEX([ChooseLevel],1):[@ChooseLevel]="Outcome"))),"Output")&"."&COUNTIF([@ChooseLevel]:INDEX([ChooseLevel],MATCH(1,0/(INDEX([ChooseLevel],1):[@ChooseLevel]="Output"))),"Activity"),".0","")))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Slight error in the above answer, I wrapped it in an IF statement to remove numbering even if no Outcome, Output or Activity was chosen.
    IF([@ChooseLevel]="","",
I've also put in an error handling column that returns a message if the business logic is not followed.  This is working as expected.  I've not come across the CHOOSE fomula before, I shall investigate.  Many thanks for your diligence on this problem.